# Contact form 7 redirect to a thank you page which does't exist

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to show a thank you page on submitting a contact form 7 form in wordpress. But I don't want to redirect it a thank you page which is an actual page. I want this page to only show when the form is submitted and no one can access this page via a link.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to redirect the page. Simply display the **thank you message** and **hide the form**.

**Add this to wp-config.php**

```
define('WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false);
```

In your contact form page. Along with contact form shortcode, add this shortcode also.

```
[wpcf7_submit_msg]
```

Add the following code into your own plugin **`index.php`** or theme **`functions.php`**

```
function wpcf7_submit_msg(){
    if(isset($_POST["_wpcf7"])){
        echo '<h2>Thank you for submitting the form _wpcf7</h2>
        <style type="text/css">
            .wpcf7{ display: none !important; }
        </style>';
    }
}
add_shortcode('wpcf7_submit_msg','wpcf7_submit_msg');
```

Note: If you don't know how to make your own plugin. Simply create new folder in `wp-content/plugins` and add new file index.php in that file add this code.

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Contact Form Submit Message */
```

Below this line, add the above code into index.php

Go to WordPress dashboard and activate the plugin **Contact Form Submit Message** and it just works.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I want to show the thank you message on a new page. I don't want to create a new page for it as it can be accessed via url.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very Simply. Thre is a free plugin [Contact Form 7 Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-redirect/)

You can create a thank you page and set it in the "Redirection Setting" tab in form setting.

Now you just have to redirect that page if any user will access that page through the URL. 
Put this code in your `functions.php` file.

```
function my_logged_in_redirect() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 'THANKYOU-PAGE-ID' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'HOME-PAGE-URL' );
        die;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_logged_in_redirect' );
```

If you want that thankyou page should not be indexed by google, you can add that page in your `robots.txt` file.

If your URL is like this, http://example.com/THANKYOU-PAGE-URL/ then do something like below.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /THANKYOU-PAGE-URL/
```

Comment: This way the page can be accessed via url by anyone and the page will be indexed by google. I don't want to create a new page for it, it should show up only when the form is submitted.

Comment: @UtkarshSingh For that, you can show up a thank you popup. With the above process, a user can't access your page because of the condition.